How to simulate non-type template parameters in C# for generic classes for compile time type safety?
Is there a way to treat integers eg. 3 and 5 as their own types with an additional property being the value they represent? Specifically I want Modulo<3> to be different to Modulo<5> to prevent them being used together in an operation that operates on multiple Modulo<T>s.
I'll explain my use case, please excuse me if this is not mathematically sound but I think it illustrates my point well.
public interface IBase
{
    static abstract int Base { get; }
}

public class FiveBase : IBase
{
    public static int Base { get; } = 5;
}

public class SevenBase : IBase
{
    public static int Base { get; } = 7;
}

public class ModuloHardcoded<T> where T : IBase
{
    int value;

    public ModuloHardcoded(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public ModuloHardcoded<T> Add(ModuloHardcoded<T> other)
    {
        return new ModuloHardcoded<T>((value + other.value) % T.Base);
    }
}

The above code allows us to create ModuloHardcoded objects with a specific integer base. While all ModuloHardcoded objects have access to the same methods and properties, they can only interact with other objects with the same type T the same way List<string> and List<int> are distinct. The problem with the above approach is that it requires a new class for every supported base, while I want to support all integer bases by default. Ideally I want something similar to below.
// T will be an integer here
public class Modulo<T>
{
    int value;

    public Modulo(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    // The below is not possible since T is a type and not an int
    public Modulo<T> Add(Modulo<T> other)
    {
        return new Modulo<T>((value + other.value) % T);
    }

}

I am aware from this question that something similar is possible in cpp, and not possible in C#, but I have tried to provide more context showing where such a feature might be wanted. How can I achieve compile time type safety, preventing me from adding two incompatible objects? I understand that I can just add fields and properties and perform runtime checks but I feel like a solution leveraging type checking would be more elegant. Is my whole premise flawed, maybe there is a simpler way to implement the desired behaviour.

Your attempt with FiveBase and SevenBase is what I'd do as well. This is otherwise not possible.

As @Sweeper wrote - you can't do this with "just" numbers. But you can greatly reduce the need for manual work with a correctly written source generator. Though it greatly depends on the usage patterns

Another option might be roslyn analyzers. Or possibly even your own domain specific language if you have some very specific use case in mind. But I have to ask, is the benefit worth the effort? The developer would presumably still run the code and discover any problems at runtime fairly quickly.

@MukundKS — Your approach with IBase, FiveBase, and SevenBase looks quite smart, but it seems to be a big overkill though. Going away from generics here would give you a much more flexible approach. Even adding a number argument to constructors would provide better flexibility.
